# How can I display my API Data from search in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm having trouble writing the function to display the API data whenever I search something. I tried to follow tutorials online, but they are using different API's, so the function and setup is completely different from mine.

I have everything working as far as displaying data. I only need my searchCoin function to showcase whatever coin I look up and to display it.

From the API, the name and id show the exact same thing, so you could target the id or name to find the correct coin

Here is my code

```
      function App() {
        const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
        const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

        useEffect(() => {
          axios
            .get(
              'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=3&page=1&sparkline=false'
            )
            .then(res => {
              setCoins(res.data);
              console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }, []);

        const handleChange = e => {
          setSearch(e.target.value);
        };

        const searchCoin = e => {
          e.preventDefault();

      I'm trying to fix this code below to work properly

        //  setSearch(
            coins.filter(coin =>
              coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
            )
          );
        };

        return (
          <div className='coin-app'>
            <div className='coin-search'>
              <h1>Search a currency</h1>
              <form onSubmit={searchCoin}>
                <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
                <button>Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            {coins.map(coin => {
              return (
                <Coin
                  key={coin.id}
                  name={coin.name}
                  price={coin.current_price}
                  symbol={coin.symbol}
                  marketcap={coin.total_volume}
                  volume={coin.market_cap}
                  image={coin.image}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to do.

1. Add another state hook to hold the filtered coins list

   ```
   const [filteredCoins, setFilteredCoins] = useState(coins);
   ```
2. add a `useEffect` to update the `filteredCoins` once the `coins` have been populated

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredCoins(coins)
    } ,[coins])
   ```
3. Use the `filteredCoins` in your map

   ```
     {filteredCoins.map((coin) => {
   ```
4. Set a `useEffect` to update the `filteredCoins` from the original `coins` on every search change

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredCoins(
            coins.filter(coin =>
                coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
            )
        )
    } ,[search])
   ```

Or run it in your `searchCoin` function like this

```
const searchCoin = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

  I'm trying to fix this code below to work properly

     setCoins(
        coins.filter(coin =>
          coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    };
```

This will run everytime `search` is updated and filter out only the ones that match

Comment: so the useeffect works to display to search value, but once I type it in and try to erase the value and add a new one, it doesn't automatically display the new value. it just makes the screen blank

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-panini-x76tr?file=/src/Coin.css here is a codesandbox showing what is happening

Comment: @Brian the reason it is happening is because you are updating the original coins list so it the filtered items are no longer there, please see my updated answer for a way to fix this. you can also see my link here https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-keller-sy3ll?file=/src/App.js:689-852

Answer (score 0):

### React Only Updates What’s Necessary

> *React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the
> desired state.* @reactjs.org

Therefore, every time when `coins` or `search` change, the App will re-render.
so we can just create a variable that filters using the `search` value, creating a variable `FilteredCoins`

```
const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin) =>
coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
```

Notice that we are using `search`, which will be different every time the state change.
Then you can just iterate `filteredCoins` in this manner:

```
   {filteredCoins.map((coin) => (
        <Coin
          key={coin.id}
          name={coin.name}
          price={coin.current_price}
          symbol={coin.symbol}
          marketcap={coin.total_volume}
          volume={coin.market_cap}
          image={coin.image}
        />
      ))}
```

sandbox to demonstrate:
https://codesandbox.io/s/coins-8ukzf

Comment: is there a reason you made a separate searchbox component or that was just to make the code cleaner?

Comment: make the code cleaner, you could also create `CoinsList` component who maps over the coins props and render each coin component.